# Parent/child logic of lists of different length

Tags: javascript

I have two lists of different length

```
var parents = [
    { name: "foo", check: true },
    { name: "foo", check: true },
    { name: "bar", check: false }
];
var children = [
    { name: "foo", check: false, override: false },
    { name: "foo", check: false, override: false }
];
```

these lists are related with this rules: (the key is the username)

- if there are many parents with a key, and a child with the same key, add 2 more children to the children list
- if there is one parent and many children linked by key, the children list doesn't change

code so far

```
function applyLogic(parents, children) {
    for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        var child = children[i];
        var sameUsername = parents
            .filter((x) => x.username === child.username);
        if(sameUsername.length === 0) {
            continue;
        }
        for(let j = 0; j < sameUsername.length; j++) {
            if(j > 0 || sameUsername.length == children.filter((x) => x.username == child.username).length) {
               children.splice(++i, 0, child);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

- the number of true checks in the parents must be mirrored by the children
- unless the child override the rule

code

```
function applyLogic(parents, children) {
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    var child = children[i];
    var sameUsername = parents.filter((x) => x.username === child.username);
    if (sameUsername.length === 0) {
      continue;
    }
    for (let j = 0; j < sameUsername.length; j++) {
      if (j > 0 || sameUsername.length == children.filter((x) => x.username == child.username).length) {
        let newItem = {
          username: child.username,
          check: child.check,
          override: child.override
        };

        children.splice(++i, 0, newItem);
      } // end if
      if (!child.override && !child.check)
        if (sameUsername[j].check) {
          child.check = true;
        }
    }
  } // end for (j)
}
```

I've been dissecting this code in many ways, but I can't make it work.

I also have some test data with the expected results (i'll use pseudo code for readability)

```
parameters:
[Parent("foo", true), Parent("foo", false), Parent("foo", true)]
[Child("foo", false, false)] 
expected: => [Child("foo", true, false), Child("foo", false, true), Child("foo", true, false)]
result: never passing

parameters:
[Parent("foo", true)]
[Child("foo", false, false), Child("foo", false, false)]
expected: => [Child("foo", true, false), Child("foo", false, false)]
result: passing for length, not passing totally (check all properties)

parameters:
[Parent("foo", false), Parent("bar", true)]
[Child("foo", false, false)]
expected: => [Child("foo", false, false)]
result: never passing

parameters: (:any: means both true and false)
[Parent("foo", true)]
[Child("foo", :any:, true), Child("foo", false, false)]
expected: => [Child("foo", :any:, true), Child("foo", true, false)]
result: all passing for length, passing totally only for :all: = false
```

Comment: How exactly is your code not working? Please be specific

Comment: Well `var child = children[I];` is not gonna work since the `i` is uppercase.

Comment: when testing the length of `children` 3 out of 5 tests are passing, when testing the object properties 1 out of 5 tests are passing

Comment: > Please be specific

Comment: https://codepen.io/francesco9001/pen/bLXegg I copied the jasmine testing and changed the labels.